# Issues with PHP, HTML, Database

Tags: html, json, database

Based on the tutorial below, I am trying to make an registration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9MvEFcJyQw

I am new on PHP an I need some help.

**These errors are showing now:**

Notice: Undefined index: Nachname in C:\wamp64\www\register.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: Email in C:\wamp64\www\register.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: Geburtstag in C:\wamp64\www\register.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: Name der Schule in C:\wamp64\www\register.php on line 9

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\register.php on line 18

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp64\www\register.php on line 36

**This is my php code:**

```
    <?php   

require "init.php";

$name = $_POST ["name"];
$name = $_POST ["surename"];
$email = $_POST ["Email"];
$birthdate = $_POST ["Geburtstag"];
$name = $_POST ["Name der Schule"];
$user_name = $_POST ["user_name"];
$password = $_POST ["password"];

$sql = "select * from user_info where email like '".$email."';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$respons = array();

if (mysql_num_rows ($result)>0) 
    {       
        $code = "req_faild";
        $message = "User already exist";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code, "message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }   
else
    {

        $sql = "insert into user_info values('".$name."','".$name."','".$email."','".$birthdate."','".$name."','".$user_name."','".$password."');";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $code = "req_success";
        $message = "Thank your for register with us. NOw you can login.";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code, "message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode($response);        
    }   
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**This is my html code:**

```
<html>

<body>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Surename: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Birthday: </td><td><input type="text" name="birthday"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Name of your School: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>User Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="user_name"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password: </td><td><input type="text" name="password"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td>
</tr>

</tanle>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybode help me?

Comment: `Nachname` isn’t even in the PHP code you have shown, so _that_ code can not cause _that_ error. // Your form field names of course have to match the keys you use afterwards to try and get the values out of the $_POST array. You have f.e. `name="birthday"` in your form, but then you try to access `$_POST ["Geburtstag"]` ... that you can not translate only half of it and then expect it to still work, should be obvious.

Comment: Make sure the value is set before using: mysql_num_rows: you can add: `if(isset($result))`

Comment: Can you tell me whats wrong here: 

if (mysql_num_rows ($result)>0)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>
```

The name you put in the "name" attribute is the name to access in php.

So if your HTML name attribute is "test_input" you can access in PHP with "$_POST['test_input']" or "$_GET['test_input']" if you form ist GET

also you can define a variable only once! If you set $name a second time, you will override your first declaration.

https://www.php-einfach.de/php-tutorial/_get-und-_post/

Answer (score 0):

make sure your variable name in your html `name="birthdate"` is what you have as a key in your `$_POST` ( `$_POST['birthdate']` ) for all your fields 
i don't see `$con` for `mysqli_query` to work with 
in your `array_push` you have `$response` but you declare it `$respons` above ( missing the `e` )